# BibTeX works, but not biblatex

Tags: biblatex

BibTeX works, but I want footnote citations, so I need `biblatex`. However, I'm having problems getting it to work. My MWE is `testbib.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\begin{document} 
Hello \cite{KandR}. How are you?
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

and `sources.bib`:

```
    @BOOK
  {KandR,
   AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
   TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
   PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
   YEAR = "1988"
  }
```

When I latex `testbib.tex`, I get several Warnings (but no errors):

1. No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
2. Citation 'KandR' undefined
3. Empty bibliography
4. There were undefined references
5. Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) testbib(biblatex)

I then run BibTeX on `testbix.aux` file and get three error messages:

1. I found no \citation commands
2. I found no \bibdata command
3. I found no \bibstyle command

and then "Process exited normally".

I return to my original file, latex in twice, and get the same Warnings. The output is the text plus [**KandR** ], without any bibliography.

I am using Texmaker 3.3.3, MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit and Windows 7 64-bit. Can anyone please help me to get this working? I have an idea or two: should I really Bibtex the `.aux` file, or *Biblatex* it? Also, I do not have a file resembling `biblatex` in my `\miktex\bin\x64` folder, although I do have a bunch of `.tpm` biblatex files in `\tpm\packages`. Lastly, I haven't yet found where I can use the command line in TeXmaker (I am doing the existing commands through Tools). So if you need me to enter a command other than `latex` or `bibtex` (maybe `biber`), please tell me where the command line is.

Comment: Since version 2, `biblatex` uses Biber instead of BibTeX as default backend. So, replace running `bibtex testbib.aux` with `biber testbib` (*without* `.aux`). (This assumes you have an up-to-date TeX distribution which includes Biber.)

Comment: ...or, if you don't want to switch to `biber`, use `[backend=bibtex]`

Answer (score 3):

The following MWE (including your `bib` file, a few minor changes to yours) should run on your system without errors and only one correct warning: `overwriting file \jobname.bib` (that tells you that file `\jobname.bib` has been rewritten. `\jobname` is changend to the name of your texfile. for example `test`. You have to run: `pdflatex test.tex`, `bibtex test`, `pdflatex test.tex`, `pdflatex test.tex`).

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83128/bibtex-works-but-not-biblatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{KandR,
  AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
  TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
  YEAR      = {1988},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex   % use BibTeX
% backend=biber    % Use biber
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document} 
Hello \cite{KandR}. How are you?
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```